# laravel policy gves flalse

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am new to laravel and now trying to learn policies so I created the following models:

```
class group extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'id','book_id',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [

    ];
    public function users(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('BOOK_DONATION\User')->withPivot('last_seen_id');
    }
}
```

and :

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email','country','state/provience','city', 'token', 'password','postal_code',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password','verfied', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function Book(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Book');
    }

    public function groups(){
        return $this->belongsToMAny('BOOK_DONATION\group')->withPivot('last_seen_id');
    }

}
```

and :

```
class group_user extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table='group_user';
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id','group_id','last_seen_id'
    ];
    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [

    ];
}
```

now the group_user is model for the intermidate table required for the many to many relation between users and groups

and here is my policy:

```
class group_userPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can view the group_user.
     *
     * @param  \BOOK_DONATION\User  $user
     * @param  \BOOK_DONATION\group_user  $groupUser
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function view(User $user, group_user $groupUser)
    {
        //
        return in_array($user->id,$groupUser->user_id);
    }


}
```

and here is the specific programming lines from controller related :

```
$grouUser=group_user::where('group_id',$group_id)->pluck('user_id');
        if(Auth::user()->cant('joinChat',$grouUser)) return redirect('/sorry');
```

now I always get redirected to sorry page but I have the right yo join chat so what is wrong?

Comment: $groupUser->user_id doesn't look like an array to me... if it is, it's poorly named.

Comment: And, if `group_user` is a Model, try to stick to naming conventions; `GroupUser` for models.

Comment: @Devon what you suggest? I need to get array of user ids from group_user model so how to do it?

Comment: If `GroupUser` has a `users()` relationship, you would just be able to call `if($groupUser->users()->contains($user->id)){ ... }`. Maybe post your model code too?

Comment: @mark group_user sounds like a pivot or intermediate table.  It's very rare to need a model for that.  You should do some more reading on how to handle many to many relationships between a User and Group model in the BelongsToMany section of Laravel docs.

Comment: @Devon yes it is intermediate table

Comment: @Devon I have edited my question

Comment: @mark You don't need a model for intermediate tables, it's a relationship, not an entity.  Do as I suggested and re-read the docs.